# How to send the byte[] data of onPreviewFrame method over socket

Tags: android, sockets, camera, streaming

I've create a simple camera application, in the onPreviewFrame method, I get the data byte array, is that the byte of image preview and how can I send it over socket from phone to phone?

```
camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

     public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //Send data to client
        outputStream.write(data, 0, data.length);                    
     }
 }
```

Is that send data array correct? If yes, how to client can receive that data at show it's at image?

Thank you.